# Android app is crashed on click entry field in android oreo 8.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin prism and we simply navigate to the other page on clicking list item.But when we click on the entry field then app is crashed and these problem occur only in android oreo.

> 04-16 11:45:47.844 D/ViewRootImpl@1993e28MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
>   04-16 11:45:47.945 D/ViewRootImpl@1993e28MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1
>   04-16 11:45:47.948 D/AbsListView(15775): onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 0
>   04-16 11:45:48.118 W/zygote64(15775): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.EntryRenderer
>   04-16 11:45:49.424 D/ViewRootImpl@1993e28MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0
>   04-16 11:45:49.499 D/ViewRootImpl@1993e28MainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1
>   04-16 11:45:49.567 V/InputMethodManager(15775): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@7e787e0 nm : com.kefi ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@3b4a99
>   04-16 11:45:49.567 D/InputMethodManager(15775): startInputInner - Id : 0
>   04-16 11:45:49.568 I/InputMethodManager(15775): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>   04-16 11:45:49.570 D/InputTransport(15775): Input channel constructed: fd=100
>   04-16 11:45:49.571 D/InputTransport(15775): Input channel destroyed: fd=96
>   04-16 11:45:49.571 D/InputMethodManager(15775): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 15775 view : com.kefi
>   04-16 11:45:49.621 D/InputTransport(15775): Input channel constructed: fd=99
>   04-16 11:45:49.622 D/ViewRootImpl@7d2b3d1PopupWindow:5ff656a: setView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{c266e36 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} TM=true MM=false
>   04-16 11:45:49.640 D/ViewRootImpl@7d2b3d1PopupWindow:5ff656a: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   04-16 11:45:49.664 V/Surface (15775): sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
>   04-16 11:45:49.664 D/ViewRootImpl@7d2b3d1PopupWindow:5ff656a: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[356,756][436,851] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 528188313600} changed=true
>   04-16 11:45:49.668 D/mali_winsys(15775): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000, [80x95]-format:1
>   04-16 11:45:49.668 D/OpenGLRenderer(15775): eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7b09dee680, 0x7afa7a1010
>   04-16 11:45:49.685 D/ViewRootImpl@7d2b3d1PopupWindow:5ff656a: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(356, 756 - 436, 851) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
>   04-16 11:45:50.027 D/ViewRootImpl@1993e28MainActivity: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) ci=Rect(0, 85 - 0, 126) vi=Rect(0, 85 - 0, 939) or=1
>   Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 viewModel is :

    using Acr.UserDialogs;
    using Kefi.Helper;
    using Kefi.Interfaces;
    using Kefi.Models.API.RequestModel;
    using Plugin.Connectivity;
    using Prism.Commands;
    using Prism.Mvvm;
    using Prism.Navigation;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace Kefi.ViewModels
    {
        public class LANIPScreenViewModel : BindableBase
        {
            private INavigationService _navigationService;
            private string _labelLANIP ;
            private string _labelSubnetMask;
            private IWebApiCallService _webApiCallService;
            private string _netmask;
            public string LabelLANIP
            {
                get {
                    _labelLANIP = LocalSettings.Lan_ip.ToString();
                    return _labelLANIP;

                }
                set { _labelLANIP  = value; }
            }
            public string Netmask
            {
                get {
                    _netmask = LocalSettings.Netmask.ToString();
                    return _netmask;
                }
                set { _netmask = value; }
            }

            public LANIPScreenViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IWebApiCallService webApiCallService)
            {
                _navigationService = navigationService;
                _webApiCallService = webApiCallService;

                //Lanipaddress();
            }
            //private async Task Lanipaddress()
            //{


            //}
            public DelegateCommand BackButtonCommand => new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("AdvancedScreen");
                });
            });
            public DelegateCommand SaveCommand => new DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                        {
                            var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(_labelLANIP, @"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$");
                            if (isValid)
                            {
                                var isValid2 = Regex.IsMatch(_netmask, @"^(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)\.(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)\.(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)\.(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)$");
                                if (isValid2)
                                {
                                    LanIpRequestModel lanIpdata = new LanIpRequestModel
                                    {
                                        kefi_device_id = App.Current.Properties["DeviceId"].ToString(),
                                        lan_ip = _labelLANIP,
                                        subnet = _netmask
                                    };
                                    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();
                                    var result = await _webApiCallService.LANIP(lanIpdata);
                                    if (result.statusCode == 200)
                                    {
                                        LocalSettings.Lan_ip = _labelLANIP;
                                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                                        DependencyService.Get<Toasts>().Show("Data changed successfully.");
                                    }
                                    else if (result.statusCode == 404)
                                    {
                                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                                        DependencyService.Get<Toasts>().Show("Couldn't complete request at this moment. Your device seems to be offline.");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                                        //DependencyService.Get<Toasts>().Show("Something went wrong!.Please try again");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    DependencyService.Get<Toasts>().Show("Subnet mask is not in correct format");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DependencyService.Get<Toasts>().Show("Lan ip is not in correct format");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                            DependencyService.Get<Toasts>().Show("Couldn't connect to internet.Please try again");
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                        //DependencyService.Get<Toasts>().Show("Internal Server Error.Please try again");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }



    And  page.xaml.cs is :

    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

    namespace Kefi.Views.Advanced
    {
        [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class LANIPScreen : ContentPage
        {
            public LANIPScreen()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AdvancedScreen(), true);
                });
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    And xaml is :

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                 xmlns:UserControl="clr-namespace:Kefi.Views.Common"
                 xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Kefi.Controls"
                 xmlns:Validations="clr-namespace:Kefi.Validation"
                 prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                 x:Class="Kefi.Views.Advanced.LANIPScreen"
                 NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
        <Grid Padding="15">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.8*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                <RowDefinition Height="0.8*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.8*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <UserControl:BackButton Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <UserControl:BackButton.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BackButtonCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </UserControl:BackButton.GestureRecognizers>
            </UserControl:BackButton>
            <Label Text="LAN IP" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#4479AA" FontSize="26" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
            <Label Text="LAN IP" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding LabelLANIP}" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="None" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <Label Text="Subnet Mask" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <!--<Label Text="{Binding LabelSubnetMask ,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="Black" FontSize="14" FontAttributes="None" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>-->
            <Entry Text="{Binding Netmask}" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="None" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <custom:CustomButton Text="SAVE" Grid.Row="7" HeightRequest="70" Style="{StaticResource blueButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
```

Comment: Do you have any code associated with this? Because with just a vague description and error we can only guess.

Comment: You said it worked on Android O (8.1), which other Android Version you tested it and worked? Just wondering if the issue you are seeing is because you are not requesting some required permissions.

Comment: App is crashed only in android oreo. And in other version it worked.

Comment: You mean that other version sdk work well?